# Suggestion for statistical analysis. Is generalized estimating equation (GEE) a good option?

Tags: spss, generalized-estimating-equations

I have two groups a G1 and control.  For both groups we measured their cell counts every 10 minutes:  0 to 650 min.

We are trying to find:

1. Difference (in cell counts) between G1 and controls - significant
2. Effect of time (on the cell count) the same for both G1 and controls

What statistic analysis do we need to use?  One of my friends told me to use the generalized estimating equation (GEE), but I am not sure.

What is GEE used for?

Comment: It may help you to read my answer here: [Difference between generalized linear models & GLMM in SPSS](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32419//32421#32421).