# How to insert temperature and precipitation data on a GEE or GLMM model

Tags: biostatistics, glmm, count-data, generalized-estimating-equations, offset

I am analysing a data of number of aphids with variation over time (32 avaliations performed every week), area (two areas), and plant position (fixed factor), with 3 replications. Because of that, I am running both GEE and GLMM (to compare the results). The problem is that for each time in each area I have the data on precipitation and temperature. And these data are important because the aphid population is highly affected by these ambient conditions. I really want to study the effect of temperature and precipitation, and I am thinking of using them as fixed factors, but it does not sound correct because they are a range of values. I have thought about using the values as an offset in the model, but I don't know if it is right and probably I will not be able to make any conclusions on how the temperature and precipitation affected the data.

Here is a small example of the data set:

- REP- repetition
- posi - plant position
- prec - precipitation
- medt maxt mint - temperature information
- area- area
- cont- number of aphids
- time- week of the count

> ```
> rep   posi prec   medt    maxt    mint   area cont time
>
>
>
> 1 s   11.03   21.60   28.20   15.10   1   22     1
>
> 1 m   11.03   21.60   28.20   15.10   1   0      1 
>
> 1 i   11.03   21.60   28.20   15.10   1   0      1
>
> 2 s   11.03   21.60   28.20   15.10   1   2      1
>
> 2 m   11.03   21.60   28.20   15.10   1   0      1
>
> 2 i   11.03   21.60   28.20   15.10   1   0      1
>
> 3 s   11.03   21.60   28.20   15.10   1   1      1
> .   .     .       .       .        .     .   . 
>
> .   .     .       .       .        .     .   . 
>
> 1 s   143.70  22.66   26.24   19.09   2   0      32
>
> 1 m   143.70  22.66   26.24   19.09   2   23     32
>
> 1 i   143.70  22.66   26.24   19.09   2   18     32
>
> 2 s   143.70  22.66   26.24   19.09   2   0      32
>
> 2 m   143.70  22.66   26.24   19.09   2   0      32
>
> 2 i   143.70  22.66   26.24   19.09   2   0      32
>
> 3 s   143.70  22.66   26.24   19.09   2   3      32
>
> 3 m   143.70  22.66   26.24   19.09   2   0      32
>
> 3 i   143.70  22.66   26.24   19.09   2   3      32
> ```

Comment: This is hard to follow. Can you provide a small example dataset to illustrate your situation?

Comment: I have edited this for English grammar based on my interpretation of what you are saying. Please ensure it still says what you want it to.

Comment: Note that it does not make sense to compare a GLMM & a GEE model, as they are answering different questions. It may help to read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32421/7290).

Answer (score 0):

More of a too long comment.

> I really want to study the effect of temperature and precipitation, and I am thinking of using them as fixed factors, but it does not sound correct because they are a range of values. I have thought about using the values as an offset in the model, ...

Offsets are mostly used for modeling rates, and temperature/precipitation are not involved in rates, so modeling them using offsets does not seem right. Apart from this, that temperature information is max/min-values, is a separate problem, but it is not solved by offsets! Maybe use max/min-temp as separete predictors?