# Which is a better estimator, averaged functions vs. A function of an average?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimators, efficiency

## Problem:

Assume that we want to estimate $f(\theta)$ with a pre-specified **strictly increasing** function $f$ and a parameter $\theta$.

Let $\hat{\theta}_1$ and $\hat{\theta}_2$ be unbiased estimators for $\theta$. My question is to compare which estimator is better for $f(\theta)$:

1. $f\left(\frac{\hat{\theta}_1 + \hat{\theta}_2}{2}\right)$, or
2. $\frac{f(\hat{\theta}_1) + f(\hat{\theta}_2)}{2}$.

## My approach:

My approach is taking an expectation on both based on Taylor's expansion of $f$, provided that they are well-defined.

1. $$\mathbb{E}f\left(\frac{\hat{\theta}_1 + \hat{\theta}_2}{2}\right) = 
   f(\theta) + \frac{f''(\theta)}{2}\text{Var}\left(\frac{\hat{\theta}_1 + \hat{\theta}_2}{2}\right) + \ldots
   $$
2. $$\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{f(\hat{\theta}_1) + f(\hat{\theta}_2)}{2} \right] = 
   f(\theta) + \frac{f''(\theta)}{2}\left(\frac{\text{Var}(\hat{\theta}_1) + \text{Var}(\hat{\theta}_2)}{2}\right) + \ldots
   $$

Here, the first-order disappears in each expectation because $\hat{\theta}_1$ and $\hat{\theta}_2$ are unbiased.

Let's further assume $f''(\theta)>0$. Then, since
$$\label{varineq}
(0 \le)
\text{Var}\left(\frac{\hat{\theta}_1 + \hat{\theta}_2}{2}\right) \le
\frac{\text{Var}(\hat{\theta}_1) + \text{Var}(\hat{\theta}_2)}{2},
$$
the first estimator (i.e. a function of averages) seems less distant from $f(\theta)$, as long as the remaining terms (order $\ge 3$) are ignored.
The last inequality comes from a simple observation:
$$
\frac{\text{Var}(\hat{\theta}_1) + \text{Var}(\hat{\theta}_2)}{2} - 
\text{Var}\left(\frac{\hat{\theta}_1 + \hat{\theta}_2}{2}\right) =
\dfrac{1}{4}\left( \text{Var}(\hat{\theta}_1) + \text{Var}(\hat{\theta}_2) - 
2\text{Cov}\left(\hat{\theta}_1, \hat{\theta}_2\right) \right) = \dfrac{\text{Var}(\hat{\theta}_1 - \hat{\theta}_2)}{4} \ge 0.
$$

## Question:

I wonder if this is logical and there is another way to justify a better estimator.

## Edit:

Let's restrict the class of $f$ by the strictly increasing ones.

Comment: An example would help, e.g.: Suppose someone gives you the mean $\theta_1$, median $\theta_2$, and size $n$ of a sample drawn from a normal parent $N(\mu,\sigma)$. What are your best estimates for $\mu$ and $\mu^2$? It should be possible to work this out using the joint distribution at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477115/asymptotic-correlation-between-sample-mean-and-sample-median -- note the answers may well be weighted averages and the covariance may be significant.

Comment: Where do you obtain the last inequality about variances?  It's not generally true. Counterexamples include the cases $\hat\theta_2 = -\hat\theta_1$ (for which the right hand side is zero) and when the $\hat\theta_i$ are independent (for which the right hand side is half the left hand side).

Comment: @whuber Oops, sorry for that. I used the opposite inequality. Now it is edited.

Comment: Bear in mind that if the function represents something other than a linear transformation of the inputs, the two will yield [different] answers to different questions. To get a sense of that, it may help to read my answer here: [Difference between generalized linear models & generalized linear mixed models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32421/7290).

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Thanks! Then, let's keep our focus on the strictly increasing $f$ (see my edit). Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Why would unbiasedness matter when transforms do not preserve unbiasedness?

Comment: @Xi'an Because $\theta$ only can be estimated consistently. It is implicitly assumed that an unbiased estimator for $f(\theta)$ cannot be directly found.

Comment: @MattF. Thanks for your comments and the example. It seems more appropriate to say I am more interested in estimating $\mu^2$ using two (possibly correlated) unbiased estimators of $\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are unbiased estimators of $\mu$ with a bivariate normal distribution.

Let $\sigma_1 = k \sigma_2$, with $k<1$, so $\theta_1$ is the more efficient estimator.

Let the correlation be $r$, with $-1<r<1$.

We seek the least-variance linear estimates for $\mu$ and $\mu^2$. The results are:

\begin{align}
\min_{a,b}Var[\mu-(a\theta_1+b\theta_2)] \text{ has }&\mu \sim \frac{(1-kr)\theta_1+(k^2-kr)\theta_2}{1-2kr+k^2}\\
\min_{c,d,e}Var[\mu^2-(c\theta_1^2+d\theta_1\theta_2+e\theta_2^2)] \text { has }&\mu^2 \sim \left(\frac{(1-kr)\theta_1+(k^2-kr)\theta_2}{1-2kr+k^2}\right)^{\!2}
\end{align}

So for functions $f$ that are quadratic or well approximated by quadratics, if $\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}$ is the best linear estimate for $\mu$, then $f\left(\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}\right)$ is the best linear estimate for $f(\mu)$. In general an appropriate weighted average inside $f$ works even better.

**Example:** $\theta_1$ is the mean of a sample from a normal parent with mean $\mu$, and $\theta_2$ is the median from the same sample. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477115/asymptotic-correlation-between-sample-mean-and-sample-median) $k=r=\sqrt{2/\pi}$, and the above formula shows that the best estimate for $\mu$ is $\theta_1$, and the best estimate for $\mu^2$ is $\theta_1^2$, i.e. ignoring the median.

**Example:** $\theta_1$ is the mean of a sample from a normal parent with mean $\mu$, and $\theta_2$ is the median of a *different* sample of the same size. Then $k=\sqrt{2/\pi}$, $r=0$, so the best estimate for $\mu$ is $(\pi\theta_1+2\theta_2)/(\pi+2)$, or $.611\theta_1 + .389\theta_2$, and the best estimate for $\mu^2$ is the square of that.

**Example:** $\theta_1$ is the mean of a sample from a normal parent with mean $\mu$, and $\theta_2$ is the *mean* of a *different* sample of the same size. Then $k=1$, $r=0$, so the best estimate for $\mu$ is $(\theta_1+\theta_2)/2$, and the best estimate for $\mu^2$ is $\left(\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}2\right)^{\!2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was more curious about general conditions of $f$ or the estimators, but this also helps.

Comment: What functions $f$ do you have in mind that aren't well approximated by quadratics, or what estimators do you have in mind that aren't distributed normally?

Comment: @inmybrain, if this is worthy of thanks, it is also worth an upvote, or a clearer specification of what situations you care about that it doesn't cover?