# Why GEE estimates are smaller than GLMM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, glmm, generalized-estimating-equations

Both are estimators that maximize the marginal likelihood, only GLMM does so by first considering the conditional probability, while GEE assumes a covariance structure of the marginal probability directly. So why should the coefficients be systematically different one from the other (GEE gives coefficients that are smaller in magnitude)?

Comment: Related: [Difference between generalized linear models & generalized linear mixed models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/32419/7290).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This actually depends on the link function -- eg, for a log link there is not a systematic difference, but for a logit link there is.

The reason is that the models are systematically different and the marginal likelihoods are systematically different.  As the simplest example consider a logistic GLMM with a random intercept, for longitudinal data indexed by person $i$ and time $t$

$$\mathrm{logit} E[Y_{it}|X_{it}=x, a_i] = a_i+x\beta$$
where $a_i\sim N(\alpha, \tau^2)$

The GEE marginal mean model is

$$\mathrm{logit} E[Y_{it}|X_{it}]=\tilde\alpha+x\tilde\beta$$

So how are $\beta$ and $\tilde\beta$ related? Well, the GLMM has
$$E[Y_{it}|X_{it}=x, a_i] = \mathrm{expit}\,(a_i+x\beta)$$
so
$$E[Y_{it}|X_{it}=x] = E_a[E[Y_{it}|X_{it}=x, a_i]]=E_a[\mathrm{expit}\,(a_i+x\beta)]$$
so
$$\mathrm{logit}\, E[Y_{it}|X_{it}=x] = \mathrm{logit}\,E_a[\mathrm{expit}\,(a_i+x\beta)]$$

The GEE has
$$\mathrm{logit} E[Y_{it}|X_{it}=\tilde\alpha+x\tilde\beta$$

These would be the same if expectations and $\mathrm{expit}$ commuted, but they don't. For a log link, the $\beta$ *would* be the same, because you can take an $e^\beta$ multiplier through the expectation, but the $\alpha$ would be systematically different.

Ok, so we know $\beta\neq\tilde\beta$ (for the true parameters, not just the estimates). Why is $|\beta|>|\tilde\beta|$?

I think this is easiest with a picture

```
expit<- function(x) exp(x)/(1+exp(x))

x<-seq(-6,6,length=50)
eta_c <- 0+1*x
mu_c <- expit(eta_m)
plot(x, mu_c,ylab="P(Y=1)",lwd=2,type="n",xlim=c(-6,6))

a<-rnorm(20,s=2)

total_m<-numeric(50)
for(ai in a){
  eta_c <- ai+0+1*x
  mu_c <- expit(eta_c)
  lines(x, mu_c, col="grey")
  total_m<-total_m+mu_c
}

mu_m<-total_m/20
lines(x, mu_m, col="blue")
```

What we see here is 20 realisations in grey of the conditional mean functions for 20 random $a_i$, and the blue curve that is the average of the grey curves, which  is the GEE mean curve.  They are basically the same shape, but the population-average curve is flatter; $\tilde\beta<\beta$.

[image: graph showing average marginal mean slopes less than conditional means]

The grey curves are all the same shape.  The derivative of $p= \mathrm{expit}\eta$ wrt $\eta$ is
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial\eta} =  \mathrm{expit}\eta$ (1-\mathrm{expit}\eta)=p(1-p)$$
so
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = p(1-p)\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial x}=p(1-p)\beta$$
That is, the  grey curves all have slope $\beta/4$ where they cross $p=0.5$ and the blue curve will have slope $\tilde\beta/4$.

One issue I've avoided here is that the GEE and GLMM logistic models are incompatible; they can't both be exactly true. But you could pretend that I used a probit link instead, where they are compatible, or that I'd looked up the relevant bridge distribution to replace the Normal distribution for $a_i$.

Comment: didn't expect such a thorough reply so quickly :-)

Comment: Is the graph comparing the right things, though? It seems to me that you are comparing the conditional GLMM with the marginal GLMM...

Comment: The slope of the grey curves where they cross 0.5 is proportional to $\beta$; the slope of the blue curve where it crosses 0.5 is proportional to $\tilde\beta$ (with the same proportionality constant)

Comment: Is there some proof of that?